# Save javascript checkbox state on page reload?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, css

I have this piece of code here:

```
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        var showMode = 'table-cell';
        if (document.all) showMode='block';

        function toggleVis(btn){
            btn   = document.forms['tcol'].elements[btn];
            cells = document.getElementsByName('t'+btn.name);
            mode = btn.checked ? showMode : 'none';
            for(j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) cells[j].style.display = mode;
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
   <h1>Andmete kustutamine</h1>
   <hr>
   <div id="mainbox">
        <form name="tcol" onsubmit="return false">
            <p id="rand">Kuvatavad tulbad:</p>

            <table class="tabl">
                <tr>
                    <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col1" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Osakond</td>
                    <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col2" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Soetusaasta</td>
                    <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col3" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> IT Number</td>
                    <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col4" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Tooterühm</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col5" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Mudeli nimetus</td>
                    <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col6" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> SN</td>
                    <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col7" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Riigivara nr</td>
                    <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col8" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Inventaari nr</td>
                </tr>
                <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col9" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Maja</td>
                <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col10" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Ruum</td>
                <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col11" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Vastutaja</td>
                <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col12" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Märkus</td>
                <tr>
                    <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col13" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> ID</td>
                    <td id="nobord"><input type=checkbox name="col14" onclick="toggleVis(this.name)" checked> Kasutajanimi</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

And it's supposed to hide columns once the certain checkbox is toggled. My problem is that whenever I reload the page... the tick from the box disappears and the colum is there again.
Is there a way to disable that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: store your checkbox value in cookie.hide columns using cookie value

Comment: use a cookie or the localstorage to save the current state of the checkbox

Answer (score 4):

You can't retain local javascript values when you refresh the page, so you're going to either have to save the values in HTML5 Local Storage, or create a cookie and store the values in there.

Answer (score 0):

You can store it in a cookie using javascript or,using php, you can store it inside a $_SESSION value and insert a condition on column.
Example:

```
<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['display_column'])){ ?>insert html <?php } ?>
```

If you need to hide multiple colums you can use an array (you can store it always inside a session)